# Am I allowed to bring mini knife in public in Singapore without applying?

Tags: air-travel, singapore

I'm going to Singapore in my winter vacation, and I've heard about that Singapore has a strict law.

So I want to ask may I bring a mini knife (see image below) to Singapore and bring it in public without applying for permission?

P.S. Don't get me wrong with the picture it should be straight I just bent it to show it's closable

#### Edit:

whole knife: `13cm`

Blade length: `5.4cm` (2<sup>2</sup>/<sub>16</sub> in)

[image: mini-knife-demo]

Comment: I am curious. Suppose we told you that it appears the knife is not long enough to fit the law (I don't know if it is or not, just bear with me.) Now, suppose we told you that, yes, we've taken a knife just like that with us and displayed it while, oh, maybe cutting an apple and had no problems. (I haven't, just bear with me a minute more.) Now, suppose you do so, and some officer of the law decides that they know better, and arrest you for displaying a weapon in public. Even if later all charges were dropped and an apology given... would it have been worth the lost vacation time?

Comment: Why do you want to take a knife in public?

Comment: There's noting in that picture to indicate the _scale_. Even if someone were familiar with Singapore law (which I'm not), they might have a hard time giving you any concrete advice without knowing how large the knife is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how big your knife is from the picture. However, there is [a list of items](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&ved=0ahUKEwjIpLj4zJLZAhXLMI8KHYe8CAIQFgh6MA0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.police.gov.sg%2F~%2Fmedia%2Fspf%2Ffiles%2Fe-services%2Ffaq-%2520items.pdf%3Fla%3Den&usg=AOvVaw3mCukHU3p77R5KGpuiVLbd) which are permissible or forbidden to import or possess.

Most categories of knives (hunting knives, diving knives etc.) are okay to have, however, you might not be able to carry them in public without a reason:

> However unlawful possession of such permissible items in any public place may constitute to an offence of Possession of Offensive Weapon or Scheduled Weapon under the Corrosive and Explosives Substances and Offensive Weapons Act

So taking your diving knife on your way to the beach is probably okay, but you shouldn't take it to the mall.

Some other categories of knives are illegal to have or import (see the same list as above), this notably includes flick knives and gravity knives which look a bit similar to yours. However, those are capable of being opened by a button or by gravity and yours doesn't look like it can do that. (as far as I can tell from the picture).

Note that nowhere does it mention pocket knives (like Swiss Army knives), so those are not regulated. If your knife is one of those, you should have no problem importing it.

It is not very common to carry knives in public though, so if you get searched (which is very unlikely), you might have to explain why you are carrying a knife. So personally I would go along with what has been said in the comments to your question and recommend you to leave your knife in your luggage/hotel unless you plan to go hiking or something along those lines.

Comment: The Corrosive and Explosive Substances and Offensive Weapons Act can be read here: https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/CESOWA1958

Comment: Sir how about my knife's blade `5.4cm (2+2/16in)` long.

Comment: With joint (since there's still a little bit of blade in the circle joint) is `6.5cm (2+11/16 in)`.

Comment: With the size is it possible to bring in public without applying?

Comment: There's no specific size limit I can find. All the rules are in the document linked above and the Act cited in the comment. That one specifically says: "“offensive weapon” includes any instrument which if used as a weapon of offence is likely to cause hurt", which is quite vague. It really depends on what you do with it and there are cases where people have gotten into trouble for rather short ones: [this guy tried to bring a 7 cm blade into a court building](http://www.straitstimes.com/singapore/courts-crime/man-jailed-for-knife-possession-at-state-courts). What do you need the knife for?